# How to open color palette on button click in mac application

Tags: objective-c

I have to open the color palette on button click in mac application,now how to use NSColorPalette.

Answer (score 1):

Add a colorwell object instead of button. Clicking on the colorwell automatically shows you the color palette. You can set and get the color from color palette through color well. See the NSColorWell documentation.